# Symfony crawler get child nodes from getted childs in foreach?

Tags: php, xml, symfony, parsing, web-crawler

I am working with [Symfony's dom crawler](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html).

XML looks like:

```
<Tours>
    <Tour id="1">
        <Termins>
            <Termin>
            ...
```

And i have working code:

```
        $crawler = new Crawler($xmlData);

        foreach ($crawler->children() as $domElement) {

            $tourId = $domElement->getAttribute('id');
            $tours = $crawler->filter('Tours Tour[id="'.$tourId .'"] Termins')->children();
```

But i want find way to working with crawler like this: (Main point is without selectors from 'top' but from element witch is in foreach already).

```
        foreach ($crawler->children() as $tour) {
            foreach($tour->first('Termins')->children() as $termin)
```

Answer (score 2):

At this moment, when you [iterate](https://github.com/symfony/dom-crawler/blob/9dd2987b66c69a2ce5624463ee2c47b3d4d47298/Crawler.php#L1091) over a `Crawler` you get an array of `DOMNode`. You can then create a new crawler for that subdocument.

```
foreach ($crawler->filter('tour') as $tour) {
    $tourCrawler = new Crawler($tour);
    $tourCrawler->attr('id'); // 1...
    foreach ($tourCrawler->filter('termin') as $termin) {
        // Access nodes or create further crawlers
    } 
}
```